# Elasticsearch NGramTokenFilter: Unknown field 'token_chars'

Tags: elasticsearch

``
I am upgrading my elasticsearch to 8.9 while creating documents using elasticsearch client I faced the following error

co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpMappingException: Error deserializing co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.analysis.NGramTokenFilter: Unknown field 'token_chars' (JSON path: settings.index.analysis.filter.nGram_filter.token_chars)

While the index get created on kibana with the same mapping but I want it to make it from elasticsearch client only

```
`{ 
    "mappings" : 
        {
            "properties": {
                "suggestion": {
                    "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "analyzed": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
                                "search_analyzer": "whitespace"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                            "weight": {
                            "type": "integer"
                            }
            }   
        }, 
    "settings" :            
        {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 1,
        "max_ngram_diff" : 20,
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                "nGram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "nGram_filter"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "nGram_filter": {
                        "type": "ngram",
                        "min_gram": 2,
                        "max_gram": 20,
                        "token_chars": [
                            "letter",
                            "digit",
                            "punctuation",
                            "symbol"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I test it your mapping and settings and it's working fine.

The error message you're seeing indicates that the Elasticsearch client is having trouble deserializing the **NGramTokenFilter** because of an unknown field `token_chars`. This could be due to a mismatch between the Elasticsearch version and the client version you're using.

The `token_chars` field is a part of the **NGramTokenFilter** and it should be recognized by the client. If it's not, it's possible that the client version you're using doesn't support this field or there's a bug in the client.

Check the compatibility of your client.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-compatibility.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me out, I am using the following version - 
elasticsearch-java - 8.9.1 
elasticsearch-rest-client - 8.9.1 
Java - 17

I don't think there is a version incompatibility. as both are the same.

I also think this might be a bug, but I didn't see any issues regarding the same on Elasticsearch GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If the both are using the same version maybe it's a bug. It'd be nice to do some tests like, creating a new index with the settings/mapping you provided and PUT into elasticsearch manually.